# AWS - Load balance to different clusters

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-web-services, port, amazon-elb

So I'm using ELB to load balance incoming requests. Is it possibile to make the ELB listen on two ports and, for example, route all the request made to port 80 to a specific set of instances, and route all the other request (to port 443), to another specific set of instances?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible using application load balancers

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer.
No, its not possible uptill now. not sure may be in future.